# $\{ x\in[n,n+1) : m(f^{-1}(\{x\}))>0\}$ has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show that if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then the set $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : m(f^{-1}(\{x\}))>0\}$ has measure zero where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

We can show that for each integer $n$, $S\bigcap [n,n+1]=\{x\in [n,n+1]: m(f^{-1}(\{x\}))>0\}$ has measure zero. But I got stuck here.
can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Let $S_n = S\cap [n,n+1)$.  Then $S = \bigcup S_n$, where the union is disjoint.  Use the countable additivity of the measure to get what you want.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I think this is what I am asking, I have no idea how to show that each Sn has measure zero.

Comment: Ah... that was not clear.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Can you prove the result if $f$ is a simple function?

Comment: Can you prove the result if $0$ is replaced by constant greater than zero? if so I can complete the proof. because $S=\bigcup\{x\in\mathbb{R} : m(f^{-1}(x))>1/n\}$

Comment: I think your decomposition $\mathbb{R}=\cup[n,n+1)$ is unnatural. I think it  is more natural to consider, if $f$ is a simple function, that is, $f=\sum c_i1_{E_i}$, where $\mathbb{R}=\cup E_i$, then the decomposition induced by $f$ is more natural. The situation that $f$ is simple is therefore solved.

Comment: @user335468 what do you mean with $m(f^{-1}(x))>0$?? because $ f^{-1}(x)$ is not a set

Comment: What is $m$...?

Comment: @saz m is the lebesgue measure

Comment: But then your questions doesn't make any sense; as @MariosGretsas pointed out $f^{-1}(x)$ is not a set and so $m(f^{-1}(x))$ is not well defined. Probably you mean $m(f^{-1}(\{x\}))$...

Comment: @saz and others, $f^{-1}(x)$ is the pre-image of the singleton $\{x\}$

Comment: Sorry about confusion, thank you yanko, $f^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(\{x\})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define

$$A_{k,n} := \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}; m \big(\{y \in [k,k+1); f(y)=x\} \big)> \frac{1}{n} \right\}.$$

Since for any $x \neq z$ the sets $$\{y \in [k,k+1); f(y)=x\} \quad \text{and} \quad \{y \in [k,k+1); f(y)=z\}$$ are disjoint, there can be at most $n$ points $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$m(\{y \in [k,k+1); f(y)=x_j\})>\frac{1}{n};$$ thus $\sharp A_{k,n} \leq n$. This implies that

$$S_n := \{x \in \mathbb{R}; m(f^{-1}(\{x\})> \frac{1}{n}\} = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} A_{k,n}$$

is countable, and therefore

$$S = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} S_n$$

is countable; in particular $m(S)=0$.

Comment: yea I was trying to do something like that, good job!

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{x : \mu(f^{-1}(\{x\}))>0\}$ has to be countable (and hence have measure $0$)because otherwise we would get uncountably many disjoint subsets of positive measure, which is impossible in a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Why is it impossible, you ask. Well, if we have such a uncountable collection $\mathcal{A}$, note that for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$, $A=\bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty}A\cup[-N,N]$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(A\cap[-n,n])=\mu(A)>0$ hence we can find a $N_A\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\mu(A\cap[-N_A, N_A])>0$. If we let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the collection of these $A\cap[-N_A, N_A]$ each $C\in \mathcal{C}$ is obviously contained in a set of the form $[-N,N]$ with $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Letting $\mathcal{C_n}:=\{C\in \mathcal{C} | C\subset [-n,n]\}$ we see that $\mathcal{C}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{C}_n$. It is impossible that all $\mathcal{C}_n$s are countable for then $\mathcal{C}$ being a countabe union of countable sets would also be countable. Let then $C_M$ be a set that is *uncountable*. The sets in $\mathcal{C}_M$ are all disjoint, have positive measure and are contained in $[-M, M]$. If we set $\mathcal{D}_n=\{D\in\mathcal{D}|\mu(D)\geq 1/n\}$ we see that $\mathcal{D}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{D}_n$ and so by the same argument as before there must exist a $\mathcal{D}_N$ is uncountable. By construction $\bigcup\limits_{D\in\mathcal{D}_n} D$ must have infinite measure, but this is impossible as $\bigcup\limits_{D\in\mathcal{D}_n} D \subset [-M,M]$.